# How to tell SignalR which user is authenticated?

Tags: c#, signalr

I'm trying to develop a SignalR test application, just to get to know it a little better. On this page, Microsoft explains how you can send a message to all connections related to one user:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/groups?view=aspnetcore-6.0#users-in-signalr

Code:

```cs
public Task SendPrivateMessage(string user, string message)
{
    return Clients.User(user).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
}
```

However, how does signalR know the "user"? I've been searching quite a lot but I can't seem to figure out how to tell SignalR upon creating the connection (or by calling a method afterwards) that this connection is this specific user, so I'm able to send a private message to that user in the future.

The thing is, the code below it is about groups. They show this example there:

```
public async Task AddToGroup(string groupName)
{
    await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);

    await Clients.Group(groupName).SendAsync("Send", $"{Context.ConnectionId} has joined the group {groupName}.");
}

public async Task RemoveFromGroup(string groupName)
{
    await Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);

    await Clients.Group(groupName).SendAsync("Send", $"{Context.ConnectionId} has left the group {groupName}.");
}
```

Here, it's clear for me that you tell SignalR "this connection (no longer) belongs to this group".

How do I do that with users?

I've already been googling for quite a while, but can't seem to find an example or explanation for just a username, instead of a bearer token or whatever.

Comment: SignalR handles connected users internally and you cannot iterate through the group. You'll have to store your connected users either in a db or in a concurrent dictionary inside the hub. The former is a better approach when dealing with load balancing.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! However, what is .User("userId") used for then, if it's done internally anyway?